# sending and retrieving data to API

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution with 2 projects:

1. Contains the API
2. the module where i can select data (combobox etc...)

in the second module i select the API as reference that way i should be able to use data from the first module (my API) `using Mollie.Api;`

The First thing i want to do is fill a combobow with all the issuers, they should be in issuers.data:

```
Issuers issuers = mollieClient.GetIssuers();

foreach (Issuer issuer in issuers.data)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(issuer.name);
}
```

the problem i have is: *mollieClient does not exist in current context*

i want to fill another combobox with methods but when i try to do it how they say i should do it doesnt work:

`Method methods = new Method();
 methods = Mollie.Api.Method.all();`

however when i do:
`Mollie.Api.Method.*` the helper gives me then all the possible methods at *, but how can i get them automaticly in my combobox?

The second thing is when the method and issuer is selected i want to send that data back to the API. The API should be able to proces this and send me a message back that the transaction was a succes.

Comment: Each project should reference the other one(right click on references for each project and check the other project in the solution tab). Also, make sure the projects are using the same .NET runtime version(right click on the project and go to properties, Application tab, Target framework dropdown)

Comment: Also, are you sure the name is `mollieClient` and not `MollieClient`, for example? Names are case-sensitive.

Comment: you can't make 2 project reference of eachother that would cause circular reference and they are both running at `.NETFramework,Version=v4.5`
yes i am sure that it is mollieClient, `MollieClient mollieClient = new MollieClient(); ` 
thanks for the comments but unfortunately it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like you're using [`mollie-api-csharp`](https://github.com/foxip/mollie-api-csharp/). You've written `mollieClient`, but [according to the source](https://github.com/foxip/mollie-api-csharp/blob/master/Mollie.cs#L300) `Mollie.Api.MollieClient` should start with a capital letter.

EDIT: Looks like you're following the [how-to-use tutorial from the repo](https://github.com/foxip/mollie-api-csharp#how-to-use-the-api-client).
I think you forgot to create the MollieClient instance before getting the issuers.

```
MollieClient mollieClient = new MollieClient();
mollieClient.setApiKey("your_api_key_here");
```

Comment: yes i am trying to follow that tutorial but it is not really working out for me ...
The code you show is code from the API i try to fill that combobox with the instances i find in my API, when i use a capital letter i still get an error:
`Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Mollie.Api.MollieClient.GetIssuers()'`

Comment: @extreme That's because you **need to create an instance of the MollieClient class before you can access its non-static members**! Put the code in my answer above your `Issuers issuers = ...` code (and change the name back to the original one) and it will work.